# How to use a module inside the Array.prototype.map() method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I am trying to call a method `out()` defined in a package named 'module.js'.
To do so, I use the variable `myModule = require('./module.js')`.
I have no problem calling `myModule.out()'`except when I am calling it inside the `Array.prototype.map()` method.
My code looks like this :

```
var myModule = require('./module.js');
myModule.out();
console.log('still ok')      // still ok
var p = [foo, bar];
p.map(function(){
  console.log('still ok');   // still ok
  myModule.out();
})
```

This code returns me :

> ReferenceError: myModule is not defined

I tried to redefine `myModule` inside the callback function but I have the following :

> Error: Cannot find module './module.js

Any idea about what I am missing ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us your module code ? Or at least the `out` function ?

Comment: The `out` function is just a `console.log`. The thing is I don't think the problem comes from it since it works well at the beginning. But maybe I am mistaken ...

Comment: the code you are showing seems good to me - are you sure you aren't overwriting myModule at some other point?